# Is it possible connect a Django app with Chatfuel?

Tags: python, django, bots, chatfuel

I have this project where I have to connect my Django app with a Chatfuel bot.

I have my admin panel, so whenever I update a field like complete certain task, I have to notify my client through the chatbot that this field change. But I can't find info for do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short Googling gave me the Info that Chatfuel has an API interface, which you can use to achieve your task.

[Read the documentation here](http://docs.chatfuel.com/plugins/plugin-documentation/json-api)

That way you can easily interact with your chatbot. The requests you can send via javascript / jQuery.